# Problem with drawing on texture

Tags: unity, c#, shaders

I'm trying to do a simple stretch-card erase effect. Everything works on the PC (both in the editor and in the build). But when I make a build for android, something goes wrong.

**Pc Version (work vell):**

[image: PC Version]

**Mobile version (clicked once at scratch-rectangle)**

[image: Mobile Version]

**Scratch-Controller script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
 
public class Scratch : MonoBehaviour
{
    //[SerializeField] private Renderer scratch;
    [SerializeField] private Camera scratchCamera;
    [SerializeField] private Material eraserMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private bool requestReadPixel = true;
 
    private Rect screenRect;
    private int left;
    private int top;
    private bool firstFrame;
    private Vector2? newHolePosition;
    private Action<float> callback;
    private Vector2 cursorPos;
    private Texture2D tex;
    private RenderTexture renderTexture;
 
 
    [SerializeField] private InteractManager interactManager;
 
    private bool isPointerPressed;
 
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        interactManager.pressPointer += PressPointer;
        interactManager.releasePointer += ReleasePointer;
        interactManager.cursorPos += CursorPosUpdate;
    }
 
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        interactManager.pressPointer -= PressPointer;
        interactManager.releasePointer -= ReleasePointer;
        interactManager.cursorPos -= CursorPosUpdate;
    }
 
    private void CursorPosUpdate(Vector2 pos)
    {
        cursorPos = pos;
    }
 
    private void PressPointer(Vector2 currentCursorPos, float time)
    {
        isPointerPressed = true;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(currentCursorPos), Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            var gameObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
 
            if (gameObject.CompareTag("Scratchable"))
            {
                if (gameObject.TryGetComponent<ScratchObject>(out var scratchObject))
                {
                    StartCoroutine(StartScratching(scratchObject));
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
 
    private void ReleasePointer(Vector2 currentCursorPos, float time)
    {
        isPointerPressed = false;
    }
 
 
 
 
    public void GetPercent(Action<float> _callback)
    {
        callback = _callback;
        requestReadPixel = true;
    }
    private void CutHole(Vector2 imageSize, Vector2 imageLocalPosition)
    {
 
        Rect textureRect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        Rect positionRect = new Rect(
            (imageLocalPosition.x - 0.5f * eraserMaterial.mainTexture.width) / imageSize.x,
            (imageLocalPosition.y - 0.5f * eraserMaterial.mainTexture.height) / imageSize.y,
            eraserMaterial.mainTexture.width / imageSize.x,
            eraserMaterial.mainTexture.height / imageSize.y);
 
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadOrtho();
 
        for (int i = 0; i < eraserMaterial.passCount; i++)
        {
            eraserMaterial.SetPass(i);
            GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
            GL.Color(Color.white);
            GL.TexCoord2(textureRect.xMin, textureRect.yMax);
            GL.Vertex3(positionRect.xMin, positionRect.yMax, 0.0f);
            GL.TexCoord2(textureRect.xMax, textureRect.yMax);
            GL.Vertex3(positionRect.xMax, positionRect.yMax, 0.0f);
            GL.TexCoord2(textureRect.xMax, textureRect.yMin);
            GL.Vertex3(positionRect.xMax, positionRect.yMin, 0.0f);
            GL.TexCoord2(textureRect.xMin, textureRect.yMin);
            GL.Vertex3(positionRect.xMin, positionRect.yMin, 0.0f);
            GL.End();
        }
        GL.PopMatrix();
        newHolePosition = null;
        /////////////////////
    }
 
    public IEnumerator StartScratching(ScratchObject scratchObject)
    {
        var scratchSprite = scratchObject.Scratch;
        screenRect.x = scratchSprite.bounds.min.x;
        screenRect.y = scratchSprite.bounds.min.y;
        screenRect.width = scratchSprite.bounds.size.x;
        screenRect.height = scratchSprite.bounds.size.y;
        if (scratchObject.RenderTexture == null)
        {
            scratchObject.RenderTexture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.Default);
        }
        renderTexture = scratchObject.RenderTexture;
 
        yield return renderTexture.Create();
 
        if (scratchObject.Texture2D == null)
        {
            left = renderTexture.width / 5;
            top = renderTexture.height / 4;
 
            scratchObject.Texture2D = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width - 2 * left, renderTexture.height - 2 * top, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        }
        tex = scratchObject.Texture2D;
 
        scratchCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        scratchSprite.material.SetTexture("_MaskTex", renderTexture);
        StartCoroutine(InputData());
 
    }
 
 
 
    public IEnumerator InputData()
    {
        newHolePosition = null;
 
        while (isPointerPressed)
        {
            Vector2 v = scratchCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPos);
            newHolePosition = new Vector2(1600 * (v.x - screenRect.xMin) / screenRect.width, 1200 * (v.y - screenRect.yMin) / screenRect.height);
            yield return null;
        }
 
 
    }
 
 
    public void OnPostRender()
    {
        if (firstFrame)
        {
            firstFrame = false;
            GL.Clear(false, true, new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        }
        if (newHolePosition != null)
        {
            CutHole(new Vector2(1600.0f, 1200.0f), newHolePosition.Value);
        }
        if (requestReadPixel)
        {
            tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(left, top, renderTexture.width - 2 * left, renderTexture.height - 2 * top), 0, 0);
            requestReadPixel = false;
            float percent = СaculatorPrercent(tex);
            Debug.Log("Percent:" + percent);
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback(percent);
            }
        }
   
    }
 
    public static float СaculatorPrercent(Texture2D tex)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < tex.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < tex.height; y++)
            {
                if (tex.GetPixel(x, y).r == 1)
                    count++;
            }
        }
        float percent = (count * 100 / ((tex.width) * (tex.height)));
        return percent;
    }
}
```

**Mask shader (use in scratch-rectangle)**

```
Shader "Masked" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Main", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MaskTex ("Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
 
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
 
            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform sampler2D _MaskTex;
            uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;
            uniform float4 _MaskTex_ST;
 
            struct app2vert
            {
                float4 position: POSITION;
                float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
            };
 
            struct vert2frag
            {
                float4 position: POSITION;
                float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
            };
 
            vert2frag vert(app2vert input)
            {
                vert2frag output;
                output.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(input.position);
                output.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(input.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return output;
            }
 
            fixed4 frag(vert2frag input) : COLOR
            {
                fixed4 main_color = tex2D(_MainTex, input.texcoord);
                fixed4 mask_color = tex2D(_MaskTex, input.texcoord);
                return fixed4(main_color.r, main_color.g, main_color.b, main_color.a * (1.0f - mask_color.a));
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

**Eraser shader**

```
Shader "MaskConstruction" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
 
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest Off
        Blend One One
        BlendOp Max
        Pass {
            Lighting Off
            SetTexture[_MainTex] {
                matrix [_UVMatrix]
                ConstantColor [_Color]
                combine texture * constant
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even know how to clarify the question, because the problem is not clear to me, the scratch square "breaks" somewhere after leaving OnPostRender.

Comment: I would suspect that this is a problem with the texture compression format. My approach would be a completely different one, though: Instead of using the low-level `GL` API I would create a separate texture for the alpha-channel of the "unscratched" material and paint on that texture using texture.SetPixels. Would you accept an answer based on this approach?

Comment: @Philipp thanks for the comment! I'd like to read your version, however I thought setPixels was pretty slow compared to GL. Of course I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is likely going to be a bit slower. But you are doing it only once to reply to a click from the user, not every frame. So it very likely does not matter in your particular use-case.